# How to void the URLClassLoader conflict?

Tags: java

In my application I was use the URLClassLoader to load database driver in runtime(The apache.dbcp provide setClassloder() paramster to dynamic loaded), but awkward thing is the application need
negotiate with mysql database so the maven need denpended on "mysql-connector-java", when dbcp call for setClassloder() that will cost the conflict, which mean dbcp will use the maven denpendency not dynamic driver vertion.

Here is the part of code that how to get URLClassLoader.

```java
private URLClassLoader getLoader() throws MalformedURLException {
    ClassLoader parent = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    File file = new File("to_jar_file");
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()};
    return new URLClassLoader(urls, parent);
}
```

In Above, the "parent" already load maven denpendency of mysql, but even didn't spicify the parent classload, in URLClassloader it will through the "AccessController.getContext()" to get it, it seem no difference to me. Or should I Create my own ClassLoader for URLClassLoader?

If I do create my own ClassLoader, when overrider the "loadClass()" and call for the "findClass()", how to get class source file in jar file(database driver file)?

Comment: Althrough the code that I provide it will work success, because the mysql-8.0 denpendency that I introduce in maven was compatibility for most mysql version, but it just seem not right for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not get the point of the two database drivers 100%, you could wright your own custom class loader - based on `URLClassLoader`:

```java
public class YourCustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    public YourCustomClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(urls, parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // Check if the class should be loaded by the parent ClassLoader
        if (name.startsWith("com.mysql") || name.startsWith("org.mysql")) {
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }

        // try to load the class using your custom ClassLoader
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = findClass(name);
            if (resolve) {
                resolveClass(clazz);
            }
            return clazz;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // If the class not found in this ClassLoader, delegate to parent ClassLoader as fallback
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // Extract class source file from JAR and load it
        byte[] classBytes = extractClassBytesFromJar(name);
        return defineClass(name, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
    }
}
```

Then you can use a custom `getLoader()` method, to get the custom class loader:

```java
private CustomClassLoader getLoader() throws MalformedURLException {
    ClassLoader parent = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    File file = new File("to_jar_file");
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()};
    return new YourCustomClassLoader(urls, parent);
}
```

For extracting a class from a jar (the implementation of this method `extractClassBytesFromJar`) you cloud have a look at `java.util.jar.JarFile` or a third-party library like [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) or the Java Archive (JAR) API.